# Is it necessary to have a license to use Visual Studio 2015 community edition?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded a VM from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines

I used my windows license key to activate windows 10.

When I launched Visual Studio, a box pops up saying:

> License: 30 day trial (for evaluation purposes only) Your evaluation
>   period has ended.

I click on the option "Check for an updated license", and it asks me to :

> Type the email address or phone number of the account you want to sign
>   in with.

What's the point of this ? I thought the Visual Studio community edition was free. Are there any restrictions based on WHICH email address or phone number I use ? How long is a license valid for ? Should I use my work or personal email address, or does it not matter? Is there a way I can just use VS without having to register anything ?

Comment: It is free, but you have to register with MS. It's their condition. You have to use your MS account. If you have questions about that license, contact MS directly and ask them. We are not MS licensing support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about software licensing that should be addressed to the software vendor.

Comment: @KenWhite - the people who would most likely know the answer are programmers on this site.

Comment: @KenWhite Also programmers are far likely to know if there will be any problem with using an unlicensed version or if there will be any trouble submitting an app as a result.

Comment: No, the people who would most likely know are the people whose product you're installing, which would be Microsoft. See the [help/on-topic] if you need a refresher regarding the guidelines here. Where do you see *licensing* in that list? If you have questions about licensing for software, take them up with that software vendor or author. We are not MS licensing support, and the guidelines don't change here just because you don't want to adhere to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to register it with your Microsoft email account. Then you can use it as usual. Just give it your Microsoft email and password.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you do need a license. The license is free and requires you to register (or confirm your registration) with Microsoft.

This ensures that are you are still in compliance with the community edition.

Registration and confirmation (or re-registration) is a condition to keep the Community Edition under an active support subscription.

Comment: "Compliance"... why would they revoke your license ?

Comment: They don't need a reason to revoke it, it is their license - but they usually revoke it if you are violating the terms of the licensing agreement. As an enterprise Microsoft customer I can confirm that they are very pedantic about licensing. The situation is a lot better these days, but it is still Microsoft and licensing is one of their biggest sources of income and they police it religiously.